# Execução do Prompt + EXE Servidor IIS pela pagina WEB

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Estou rodando um comando de um executável pelo CMD do software Blue Prism, testei local e funcionou, porém estou com um dúvida para quando eu subir em produção, pois o servidor IIS vai ter o executável porém o cliente não terá, há a possibilidade de rodar o CMD no servidor de um cliente que não tem acesso a esse servidor.

```
        si.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Program Files\\Blue Prism Limited\\Blue Prism Automate\\";
        si.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        si.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        si.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c AutomateC.exe /user 123 123 /run Processo_teste
        si.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        si.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        si.Start();
        string output = si.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        si.Close();
```

No caso esse código vai tentar localizar o diretório Blue Prism e executar o AutomateC.exe, mas em 99% dos casos o usuário não vai ter esse executável, alguém já passou por algo do tipo?

Comment: Vai executar no servidor, desde que a conta da aplicação tenha privilégio para isso... Mas como eu disse vai rodar no SERVIDOR, não espere que isso tenha algum resultado na máquina do usuário que estiver acessando o site

Comment: Leandro vou dar uma olhada espero que esteja certo mas ainda não obtive resposta do pessoal de infra, obrigado pelo comentário

Comment: É que aqui não tem mágica, você precisa entender os escopos de Client e Server Side... A menos que você construa uma estrutura específica para isso, você não conseguirá esse programa na máquina do usuário e muito menos se ele estiver acessando a sua aplicação pelo browser

Comment: E a arquitetura dessa solução não é algo tão trivial assim.